# python kivy generating buttons linked to jsonstore items in a for loop

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using a for loop to generate a button for every key in a jsonstore.
The buttons are all added to the layout correctly and the button.text is correct but when the button calls the callback, they all link to the same key. (the last key)

here is the code:

```
def show_saved_conditions(*args,**kwargs):

    self.label7 = Label(text = str(self.store[self.btns.text], size_hint = (.3,.3), pos_hint = {'x':.3,'y':.5}, color = (0,0,1,1)))
    self.layout.add_widget(self.label7)

def view_saved_conditions(*args, **kwargs):

    x = 0
    y = 0

    for i in self.store.keys():

        self.btns = (Button(text = i, size_hint = (.2,.1), pos_hint = {'x':x,'y':y}, on_release = show_saved_conditions))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btns)

        x +=.2

        if x >= 1:
            y+=.1
            x = 0
```

pretty sure this question has been asked before but i was unable to find a post specific enough for me to relate to.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

## Problem - Always refer to the last button

In `show_saved_conditions()` method, it is always using `self.btns.text` which is the last button added to the layout.

```
self.label7 = Label(text = str(self.store[self.btns.text], size_hint = (.3,.3), pos_hint = {'x':.3,'y':.5}, color = (0,0,1,1)))
```

## Solution

In the example, it demonstrates `on_touch_down` event.

[Touch event basic](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def move(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class CreateButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == "right":
                print(self.id, "right mouse clicked")
            elif touch.button == "left":
                print(self.id, "left mouse clicked")
            else:
                print(self.id)
            return True
        return super(CreateButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class OnTouchDownDemo(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OnTouchDownDemo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build_board()

    def build_board(self, *args):
        # make 9 buttons in a grid
        for i in range(0, 9):
            button = CreateButton(id=str(i), text=str(i))
            self.add_widget(button)


class OnTouchDownApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return OnTouchDownDemo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    OnTouchDownApp().run()
```

### ontouchdown.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<CreateButton>:
    font_size: 50

<OnTouchDownDemo>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 3
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 150
    col_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 150
    padding: [10]
    spacing: [10]
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `*args` argument to your `show_saved_conditions()` method contains the `Button` instance that was pressed. So that method could be:

```
def show_saved_conditions(self, btn_instance):

    self.label7 = Label(text = str(self.store[btn_instance.text], size_hint = (.3,.3), pos_hint = {'x':.3,'y':.5}, color = (0,0,1,1)))
    self.layout.add_widget(self.label7)
```

Since you used `self` in the method, I have assumed that this is an instance method and the correct first arg is `self`. If it is not an instance method, then just remove the `self` arg, but then where does the method get the value for `self`?

Of course, this method will overwrite `self.label7` each time that it is executed.